# How to Stop Metal Squeak on Kinetic Sculpture

Tags: metal, lubrication, squeak

I have a kinetic sculpture in my front yard that's basically just a pretty weathervane.  The top moving part has a tube on the bottom that slips over the pole in the ground.  When the top part moves direction with the wind it is squeaking horribly (metal on metal).

I don't think lubricating it with an oil will do much since it will run down and/or be rubbed off is a short amount of time.

Is there any durable tape, maybe silicone based, that I could wrap on the pole that would last a decent amount of time?  Any other possible solutions?

Comment: Heavy oil or grease. That's what they were invented for. It's a problem as old as the iron age. Anything like tape will probably impart too much friction, and silicone is rarely used as a wear film. It's too soft.

Comment: Either that or rebuild the thing to use something like a nylon sleeve or ball bearing set.

Answer (score 3):

Needs a bearing.

Lacking pictures, a plastic tube over the pole seems most likely. Possibly a sintered bronze bushing full of oil. Might also need a bearing at the top of the tube where it sits on the pole, once you sort the noise from the bottom of the tube rubbing.

Or re-engineer the whole thing to use skate bearings, which happen to be a good mixture of low-friction and low-cost.

Comment: Teflon tube in various ID / OD and stiffness: https://www.mcmaster.com/products/tubing/trade-name~teflon-/

Comment: I thought of just using grease at first, but for a weather vane type of use, grease alone might be too sticky.

Comment: Or a teflon/delrin/nylon bushing where the "tube" and "pole" interface.